# Change font of DatePickerDialog Calendar

Tags: android, kotlin, datepicker, datepickerdialog

I want to set Roboto font across the app instead of using the device's system font.

In our project, we are still using android.app.DatePickerDialog. To change the font, I added a custom style on the instance of DatePickerDialog but only the font of the header is being changed.

Is it possible to change the font of the calendar view of DatePickerDialog?

[image: datepickerdialog calendar]

****DatePickerDialog****

```
val c = Calendar.getInstance()

DatePickerDialog(
            requireContext(),
            R.style.DatePickerDialogTheme,
            dateListener,
            c.get(Calendar.YEAR),
            c.get(Calendar.MONTH),
            c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)
        )
```

**Custom Style**

```
<style name="DatePickerDialogTheme" parent="ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.MaterialCalendar">
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="fontFamily">@font/roboto</item>
        <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/roboto</item>
</style>
```